# CakePHP advice on how to do a Jquery Tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp, tree

I want to have a file folder menu tree manager in CakePHP, using the built in Tree behaviour and with ajax editing using JQuery or another Javascript library.

I am working in cakePHP 1.3 app - if anyone has a good tutorial or can help me get the integration of a plugin that will work with Cake that would be great!

I have seen the jsTree plugin of JQuery but I'm not sure how to go about using that alogn with the CakePHP functions.

- I want to have drag and drop of menu items and their children for re-ordering
- I want to allow CRUD of nodes on the tree
- other basic tree functions.

Comment: Please show something that you have tried, this is not a free coding work site.

Comment: hey Dunhammzz in fact I put "advice" and tutorial link in my question - wasn't asking for code itself, am just wanting pointers from anyone who has done a similar thing before. Anyway, you are correct to point out the ambiguity still in the way I phrased things. 

I realised I need to get to grips better with the cake way fo doing ajax so that I can have my Js talk to the tree methods of cake.

Comment: [http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2008/02/12/drag-and-drop-using-ext-js-with-the-cakephp-tree-behavior/](http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2008/02/12/drag-and-drop-using-ext-js-with-the-cakephp-tree-behavior/) Check out the above link! Might help.

Comment: @LakshmanSrikanth: That isn't an answer; when you hit 50 rep, you'll be able to leave comments like this.  Be careful doing it now, as you are a new user and vulnerable to being flagged as a spammer and being blocked from using StackOverflow.

Answer (score -2):

The tree behavior is your friend.